# Rails 6 Bulma integration Undefined variable in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bulma, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I want to use Bulma CSS framework in my Rails 6 application and for that I am following this [tutorial](https://blackninjadojo.com/css/bulma/2019/02/27/how-to-create-a-layout-for-your-rails-application-using-bulma.html) but there are a few differences in my context:

1. I want to use **bulma-rails** gem.
2. I don't want to use webpack and thus I have removed webpacker from my application and made related changes such that the application uses the asset pipeline which was the default in Rails versions less than 6.

With that when I access the root page in my application I am facing following error

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-08-03 20:24:35 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.haml
  Rendering welcome/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 6.5ms | Allocations: 3376)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.haml (Duration: 94.4ms | Allocations: 21476)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 108ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 24374)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (Error: Undefined variable: "$white-bis".
        on line 9:20 of app/assets/stylesheets/_layout.scss
>>   background-color:$white-bis;

   -------------------^
):
  
app/assets/stylesheets/_layout.scss:9
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2021:20:24:35 IST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 123078
- -> /
```

If I comment out the following part

```
background-color:$white-bis;
```

from the `.header` style defined in `app/assets/stylesheets/_layout.scss` (shown ahead) then the page loads successfully

But I would like to retain that style. Can anybody please help me in identifying the problem and fixing it?

In my understanding the following import in my `app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss` (shown ahead)

```
   @import 'bulma';
```

should import the file [app/assets/stylesheets/bulma.sass](https://github.com/joshuajansen/bulma-rails/blob/f731ffcf1b4c5b6691a819746469672a30839d72/app/assets/stylesheets/bulma.sass) which is part of `bulma-rails` gem version `0.9.1` I am using. If that is correct, then that file already has following import in it

```
@import "sass/utilities/_all"
```

and the variable I am seeing error about is defined in one of the files imported in turn by the above shown import. Then why I am getting error?

**Below I am sharing my code**

**Gemfile**

```
ruby '3.0.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0'

gem 'bulma-rails', '~> 0.9.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.0.7'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/_layout.scss**

```
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color:$white-bis;
  padding:2rem 1.5rem;
}

.section {
  display:flex;
  flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss**

```
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'bulma';
@import '_layout';
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
 *
 *= require main
 *= require_self
 */
```

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(  )
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
- app_name = 'MyApp'

!!!
%html<
  %head<
    %meta{ content: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type" }
    %meta{ name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" }
    %title= app_name
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  %body<
    %header.header<
      .container<
        %nav.level<
          .level-left<
            .level-item<
              = app_name
          .level-right<
            %p.level-item<
              %a.button<
                %span.icon<
                  %i.fa.fa-github
                %span GitHub

            %p.level-item
              = link_to("Manage Users", nil, :class => "button is-dark is-outlined")
    %section.section<
      .container<
        = yield
    %footer.footer
      .container<
        = "Copyright © 2021 #{app_name}. All rights reserved."


  [1]: https://blackninjadojo.com/css/bulma/2019/02/27/how-to-create-a-layout-for-your-rails-application-using-bulma.html
  [2]: https://github.com/joshuajansen/bulma-rails/blob/f731ffcf1b4c5b6691a819746469672a30839d72/app/assets/stylesheets/bulma.sass
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to resolve the error I shared in my post above. Sharing the answer below.

In `app/assets/config/manifest.js` replaced following

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

WITH

```
//= link application.js
//= link application.css
```

**Solution References**

Found the above solution from https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/474. To be specific following comments in the referenced link helped

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/474#issuecomment-374958102

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/474#issuecomment-597563991

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs (found the reference to this in https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/474#issuecomment-554535369)

Thanks.